# Topological space with some conditions

Tags: gn.general-topology, tag-removed

Can one give an example of non-compact space $X$ which satisfies the following conditions:

- the countable union of compact subsets is relatively compact,
- for every closed noncompact subset $A$ of $X$ there is a positive lower semicontinuous function on $X$ which is bounded on every compact subset of $X$ but unbounded on $A$.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology would be a good reference.

Comment: Any reason why you're interested in such a space? That may help to shape answers.

Comment: If $X$ is like this then $C(X)$ with compact-open topology is a quasi-barrelled (DF)-space. I'm looking for the example of the lcs space which is like this, but is not normed. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe such a space cannot exist for the following reason:

Suppose it does. By the second requirement, there should be an unbounded function $f: X \to (0, \infty)$, which is bounded on every compact set. This means we have countably many points $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots$ such that for each $n$ the inequality $f(x_n)\ge n$ holds. The singletons $\lbrace x_n\rbrace$ are finite sets, therefore compact. By the first requirement, the set $\lbrace x_n| n\in\mathbb{N}\rbrace$ is therefore relatively compact and so its closure must be compact. But then $f$ is unbounded on a compact set, which is a contradiction.